# How to convert c# Datetime into Foxpro Date

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-foxpro

I've converted FOX PRO tables using OLEDB and I am using tables in c# ,when I am inserting data into tables it's working fine but when i am inserting date field(present day)date it's showing error data type mismatch.

dateformat dd/MM/yyyy only date no time.

```
string tdate = datetime.now.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

when I am inserting into tables I am passing value ctod('"+tdate+"');

```
string query = "select * from table1 where ordcust='" + account + "'"; 
OpenConnection(); 
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
{
   string ordcust = dr[0].ToString(); 
   string ordnum = dr[1].ToString(); 
   DateTime orddate = DateTime.Now; 
   string vara=orddate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
   string cs = "insert into resulttable(ordercustomer,ordnumber,orddate) values ('" + ordcust + "','" + ordnum + "', ctod('" + vara + "') )";
}
```

Comment: Can you please show [mcve] for your work? I _strongly_ suspect you save your DateTime values as a string which is a bad idea. And it should be `DateTime.Now.ToString` since C# is case sensitive.

Comment: you can try to use .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss"); Although it`s a bad idea as Soner mentioned

Comment: Also, How is the mySql tag relevant to this question?

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* suspect you are a victim of [choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). You should never store your `DateTime` values with their `string` representations. Just pass their values *directly* in a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

My suggestions;

- Define your `DBTYPE_DATE` on for OleDb Type which is mapped `System.DateTime` in .NET side which is mapped `OleDbType.Date` in parameter type.
- Pass your `DateTime.Now` directly to your parameterized query.

Also be aware of: [The case against `DateTime.Now`](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Comment: string query = "select * from table1 where ordcust='" + account + "'";
            OpenConnection();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {string ordcust = dr[0].ToString();
                        string ordnum = dr[1].ToString();   DateTime orddate = DateTime.Now;
                        string vara=orddate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        string cs = "insert into resulttable(ordercustomer,ordnumber,orddate) values ('" + ordcust + "','" + ordnum + "',ctod('" + vara + "') )";

Comment: @chechu Update this in your question with `edit` button under it.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean that you "converted" FoxPro tables using OLEDB? Your code doesn't look right, not only for FoxPro but for any SQL database. You should use parameters anyway. It would look like:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\Path To Your Data\"))
{
    string query = "select * from table1 where ordcust=?";
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", account);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        string ordcust = (string)dr[0];
        string ordnum = (string)dr[1];
        DateTime orddate = DateTime.Now;
        string vara = orddate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        string cs = "insert into resulttable (ordercustomer,ordnumber,orddate) values (?, ?, ?)";

        var insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(cs, con);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", ordcust);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", ordnum);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p3", orddate);

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```